# Wrong value / Number stored as Text - Apache POI

Tags: java, arrays, excel, apache-poi, output

I'm working on an application which get data from excel file and output one excel after few operations.
I got 2 issues, the first one is that one :

On my main excel file, I have this value `170299024773` and in Excel it's appear like that `1.703E+11` and then on the output file I get `1.70299E+11` and the exact value is `170299000000`. 
So as you see, it's not the value of the main file. 
Morever, for this cell, I have the error "Number stored as text", and then I fix this error from Excel I got `1.70E+11`.

I saw few tips about the Nember stored a text and in particular DataFormatter but it's doesn't change anything in my case

The code I use to get data of excel sheet to array :

```
private static String[][] sheetToArray(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet sheet, int nbCol){
    String[][] tmp = new String[sheet.getLastRowNum()+1][nbCol];

        for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getLastRowNum()+1; i++) { //Config1 to array
            Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
            DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();
                for (int j = 0; j < nbCol; j++) {
                    Cell cellC1 = row.getCell(j);
                     tmp[i][j] = df.formatCellValue(cellC1);
                }
            }
        return tmp;
    }
```

Many thanks in advance guys...

Edit : I fix the wrong value adding

```
switch (cellD2.getCellTypeEnum()){
       case STRING:
             tmp[i][j] = df.formatCellValue(cellC1);
             break;
        case NUMERIC:
             tmp[i][j] = String.valueOf(cellC1.getNumericCellValue());
        }
 }
```

But now, I have some decimal value added to my numeric state... To solve it I should use DataFormatter but in that case I will lost the right data

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51682898/how-do-i-edit-pattern-in-dataformatter/51683823#51683823 for the same problem.

Comment: I fix one statement but it add some decimal to my numeric value i.e edit @AxelRichter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `DataFormatter` is used there is no need determining the cell types. `DataFormatter` will always get the values as `String` and as they are shown in the `Excel` cells (not in all cases as shown in edit bar). So if the cell shows `1,70299E+11` then `DataFormatter` also will get "1,70299E+11". If this is not the wanted value, then `DataFormatter` must be told what else it shall do than interpreting cell formats as `Excel` will do.

For example the value `170299024773` will be shown as `1,70299E+11` in `excel`cells if cell format `General` is used. If this is unwanted, then  either the cell format must be changed in `Excel`. Using number format `0` for example, what means: show integer values as long this is possible. Or `DataFormatter` must be told that it shall interpreting cell format `General` different than `Excel`.

The following shows how telling `DataFormatter` that it shall interpreting cell format `General` as `#.###############`.

Excel:

[image]

Code:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ExcelDataformatterLikeCalcExample {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook wb  = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelExample.xlsx"));

  DataFormatter df = new DataFormatter();

  df.addFormat("General", new java.text.DecimalFormat("#.###############"));

  Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {

     String value = df.formatCellValue(cell);
     System.out.println(value);

   }
  }
  wb.close();

 }

}
```

Result:

```
axel@arichter:~/Dokumente/JAVA/poi/poi-4.0.0$ java -cp .:./*:./lib/*:./ooxml-lib/* ExcelDataformatterLikeCalcExample 
170299024773
```

Comment: Many thanks for the explaination, I see better how it works ! ;)